# what means predefined string format?

Tags: scala

This is my code and I got comment said " can I use the predefined string format?", what is predefined string format, how can I do that?

```
val uri = new URI(baseUrl + "?provider=" + provider + "&format=" + format)
```

Comment: I'm guessing they meant `URI(s"$baseUrl?provider=$provider&format=$format")`?

Comment: You'd rather ask your teammate ;)

Comment: @Tim https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-string-formatting-java-string-format-method/ that's they mean, thank you

Comment: I don't particularly rate Alvin Alexander. In my view the code I gave is a better solution than `String.format`. It is certainly shorter!

Comment: _NOTE: As of Scala 2.10 this approach is out of date. The preferred approach is to use the Scala String interpolator method._ Do what Tim says!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clean "Scala" way to do this:

```
val uri = new URI(s"$baseUrl?provider=$provider&format=$format")
```

A decent editor like IntelliJ IDEA will highlight this so that it is clear which parts are code and which parts are plain text.

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* a proper way of constructing a URI, and neither is using a string interpolator such as `s"..."` as suggested in the other answer or by your coworker. The reason is that it is going to break as soon as `provider` or `format` contain “weird” characters such as `#` or `&`. That can lead to all kinds of bugs, including security vulnerabilities.

Unfortunately, Scala doesn't come with an easy built-in way to construct URI query strings. You should use some URI abstraction from a library such as akka http or http4s.

For instance, with http4s you can write

```
val uri = uri"https://stackoverflow.com".withQueryParam("provider", provider)
```

That will take care of all the necessary escape sequences and the like.